# Number of bit strings of length 19 that contain either 000 or 11.

Tags: combinatorics

I have a bit string of length 19. How many bit strings of length 19 contain three consecutive 0s or 2 consecutive 1s?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ which contain neither $000$ nor $11$.
Let $b_n$ be the number of strings which satisfy these conditions, and also end with a $0$.

By conditioning on whether the string of length $n$ ends with $10$ or $100$, you can show
$$
b_n = b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}
$$
The above formula gives you a way to recursively compute $b_n$. For $n=19$, this is doable with pen and paper. You can also get an analytical result by [solving this recurrence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) However, the expression you get is [not nice](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=b(n)+%3D+b(n-2)+%2B+b(n-3),+b(0)+%3D+0,+b(1)+%3D+2,+b(2)+%3D+3).

To find $a_n$, use the fact that $$a_n=b_n+b_{n-1}.\tag{$n\ge 1$}$$ Proving this is left to the reader.